# How to copy latex equations as word equations from emacs?

Tags: latex

How can I copy LaTeX-equations from an emacs editor to an MS-Word equation, like the following does for Browsers instead of emacs: https://github.com/idf/LaTex2Word-Equation

Comment: From looking at the source code it appears that MS-Word is using MathML to store formulas. I've doubts that the ready-made tool exists for what you want to do, but there's a Perl program: http://dlmf.nist.gov/LaTeXML/ that claims to convert LaTeX to MathML. (I'm afraid it will only convert some small subset of LaTeX, not related to the document layout and such). Anyhow, that seems like a place to start.